# Coding the adjacency matrix for a graph in java and counting triangles

Tags: java, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I have very little programming experience, so for practice I wanted to "construct" a graph in java by coding its adjacency matrix with a two dimensional array. Specifically, I want to construct the red graph found here https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/Ramsey44.shtml, but what I coded gives me less edges in the matrix than there should be. Here is what I have so far:

public static int[][] createGraph(){

```
int[][] graph = new int[17][];
for(int i=0; i<17; i++){
  graph[i] = new int[i+1];
}

for(int i = 0; i<17; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j<=i; j++){
    if(i-j == 1 || i-j == 2 || i-j == 4 || i-j == 8){
      graph[i][j] = 1;

    }
  }
}
return graph;
```

There are 68 edges in the graph, so there should be 68 1's in the lower triangle of the adjacency matrix, which is what I'm trying to construct, but when I manually count them, when I print it, I find 59 of them. I don't know why there are edges missing. I'm guessing that assigning an edge based on the difference between the column number and the row number is not the same as the "difference between vertices" as in the website. What should I do instead?

Also my next exercise will be to count the number of triangles in the graph. I have an idea on how to do that, but could I get a hint?

Comment: You are restricting the construction to one triangle of the matrix but you may not restrict the construction of index pairs for connected nodes to another half of the matrix. - Look at the printout: there won't be index pairs with `|i-j|>8` which is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are restricting the construction to one triangle of the matrix but you may not restrict the construction of index pairs for connected nodes some other part of the matrix, i.e., the diagonal "strips" with `|i-j| <= 8`. Therefore:

```
if(i-j == 1 || i-j == 2  || i-j == 4  || i-j == 8 ||
   i-j == 9 || i-j == 13 || i-j == 15 || i-j == 16){
```

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense, so there should be overlap right, since this should only add 9 more, not double the amount I have? Also, would it be simpler for me if I construct the full adjacency matrix instead of just the lower half?

Comment: The extended test doesn't produce array elements outside the lower triangle. - It would not change much if you fill the entire matrix because you'd just add the setting of `graph[i][j]`.

Comment: Thank you! I count all 68 now! I'll tackle my second part now. I looked it up, it's a much more computationally difficult problem than expected.